# Seeing recent folders not just files in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, files, directory

I am using 'files' (aka Nautilus, apparently) 3.36.3, standard in Ubuntu 20.04.
Is there a way to see recent folders and not just files?  Currently I never see folders here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Directories themselves will not appear here but, if you want to open a directory where one of the listed files exists, you can right click and choose "Open Item Location":

[image: Nautilus - Open Item Location]

Comment: yes I know of this functoin but its an extra mental step in a tedious process I repeat tens or possibly hundreds of times a day - is there a record somewhere in linuxland of when folders were last accessed?